# Number of valid parenthesis

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, catalan

I have to find out the number of valid parenthesis.Parenthesis are of two type `[] ,()`. How many ways are there to construct a valid sequence using X and Y number of `[] ,()`. For this problem we consider `([])` is invalid way i.e `() can't hold [].`
Is there any better solution than recursion.

```
For Example X=1 and Y=1
[]()
()[]
[()]
```

Comment: The formula for `X=N, Y=0` is `2^(N-1)` but I haven't had enough coffee to take that any further. I think there is a reasonable formula.

Comment: You ask "is there any better solution than recursion?" Perhaps if you showed your recursive solution it would be possible to give you the next step in turning it into a DP program. The hardest part (figuring out the recurrence relations) should already be done.

Comment: @stark I don't think that's right -- for `X=N, Y=0` (and also for `X=0, Y=N`) the answer is the `N`th Catalan number. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number under "Applications in Combinatorics".

Comment: @PaulHankin Where I differ from the Catalan numbers is whether `(()())` is valid.  If it is, then I think the Catalan numbers are correct, if not then 2^N.  Obviously, we are both assuming `)(` is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Because square brackets cannot be inside round brackets, every sequence of round brackets has to be complete (i.e. the count of the number of open minus close brackets is back down to zero) before each occurance of a square bracket.

```
  1      012    1      0  
()[(())()][[()()]((()))]()
10 121010   1010 123210 10
```

This effectively means that the square brackets split the round brackets into seperate independent sequences:

```
   1   0   1   2   1   0
...[...]...[...[...]...]...
```

where complete sequences of round brackets can be placed anywhere between the square brackets.

As mentioned by Paul Hankin, the number of valid sequences of just one type of brackets is given by the [Catalan Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics). This gives you the number of valid sequences for the square brackets, and the number of valid sequences for any number of round brackets to be inserted somewhere inbetween the square brackets.

Unfortunately, finding out in what ways the round brackets can be distributed to the different locations inbetween the square brackets is a partitioning problem, and the logical way to solve this is by recursion. So this train of thought could lead to an algorithm, but not to one which avoids recursion.

However, the number of recursions needed to find partitions is much smaller than the Catalan number (e.g. 20 has 627 partitions, but the Catalan number for 20 is 6,564,120,420), so this method will be much faster than recursively enumerating every valid sequence.

---

Here's a simple example to demonstrate how this would work:

> X=2, Y=3

The valid sequences of square brackets:

> CatalanNumber(2) = 2
>
> ```
> 1. [ ] [ ]  
> 2. [ [ ] ]
> ```

The positions for the round brackets:

> 2 × X + 1 = 5
>
> ```
> 1[2]3[4]5
> 1[2[3]4]5
> ```

The partitions of the round brackets:

> p(Y) = 3
>
> ```
> 3
> 2,1
> 1,1,1
> ```

The permutations of the partitions:

> partition: 3 (number of parts: 1)
>   → 5 = 5
>
> ```
> 3,0,0,0,0  0,3,0,0,0  0,0,3,0,0  0,0,0,3,0  0,0,0,0,3
> ```
>
> partition: 2,1 (number of parts: 2)
>   → 5 × 4 = 20
>
> ```
> 2,1,0,0,0  2,0,1,0,0  2,0,0,1,0  2,0,0,0,1  
> 1,2,0,0,0  0,2,1,0,0  0,2,0,1,0  0,2,0,0,1  
> 1,0,2,0,0  0,1,2,0,0  0,0,2,1,0  0,0,2,0,1  
> 1,0,0,2,0  0,1,0,2,0  0,0,1,2,0  0,0,0,2,1  
> 1,0,0,0,2  0,1,0,0,2  0,0,1,0,2  0,0,0,1,2
> ```
>
> partition: 1,1,1 (number of parts: 3, identical: 3)
>   → (5 × 4 × 3) / (1 × 2 × 3) = 10
>
> ```
> 1,1,1,0,0  1,1,0,1,0  1,1,0,0,1  
> 1,0,1,1,0  1,0,1,0,1  1,0,0,1,1  
> 0,1,1,1,0  0,1,1,0,1  0,1,0,1,1  0,0,1,1,1
> ```

The valid sequences of round brackets:

> CatalanNumber(3) = 5
>
> ```
> 1. ()()()
> 2. ()(())
> 3. (())()
> 4. (()())
> 5. ((()))
> ```
>
> CatalanNumber(2) = 2
>
> ```
> 1. ()()
> 2. (())
> ```
>
> CatalanNumber(1) = 1
>
> ```
> 1. ()
> ```
>
> CatalanNumber(0) = 1
>
> ```
> 1.
> ```

The valid sequences per partition:

> ```
> 3,0,0,0,0  5 x 1 x 1 x 1 x 1  =  5
> 2,1,0,0,0  2 x 1 x 1 x 1 x 1  =  2
> 1,1,1,0,0  1 x 1 x 1 x 1 x 1  =  1
> ```

The total number of valid sequences:

> Square brackets: 2
>   Round Brackets: 75
>
> ```
>  5 x 5 = 25  
> 20 x 2 = 40  
> 10 x 1 = 10
> ```
>
> Total: 2 × 75 = 150

Answer (score 1):

For any given combination of grouped, self-enclosed round parentheses and a given arrangement of square brackets, we can use the multiset combination to determine the number of arrangements:

```
n + k - 1 choose k, where k is the smaller of the number of self-enclosed parenthetical groups and the total number of square brackets, and n is the larger of the two + 1.
```

The number of arragements of square brackets is the nth Catalan number.

One way to generate the groups of parentheses is to assign an increasing number of groups, and calculate the number of distinct permutations for each partition of (X - number of assigned groups) multiplied by the sum of the parts-as-nth-Catalan. For example:

```
X = 4
Counts for each grouping:

1 group: Cat 3
2 groups: Cat 2 * 2 + 1 // partitions [2,0] * 2 and [1,1]
3 groups: 3 // partition [1,0,0] * 3
4 groups: 1 // partition [0,0,0,0]
```

I have yet to think of a way to avoid the partitions and would be interested to learn.

Comment: Hi again. We're saying more or less the same thing, aren't we?

Comment: @m69 yes, I think so.

Comment: @m69 but I think we may both be missing something relating to the recursive construction of parentheticals. You start with one; then you put the next one either to the left of or enclosing each possibility in f(n-1). `1: (); 2: ()() (()); 3: ()()() (()()) ()(()) ((())) etc.` How can we use that construction to generalize the answer for both parentheses and brackets?

Comment: I can only see this leading to an algorithm which recursively enumerates all possibilities, which is what the asker is trying to avoid. (Btw, you're missing `(())()` )

Comment: "Avoid recursion" probably means "avoid a ridiculously huge number of recursions" anyway. The catalan number for 20 is 6,564,120,420 while the number of partitions of 20 is 627, so I'd say that partitioning recursively is the lesser evil.

Comment: @m69 good point. It might just be a good enough method. But I think by "recursion," the OP may have meant actually enumerating all possibilities.

Comment: It doesn't seem as if we'll be getting feedback anytime soon, so I propose that we're done here :-)

Comment: @m69 yea, leave it to the pros. But I'd be interested in learning a more efficient DP for this.